# How to load jars dynamically from different locations into current class loader?

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

Whenever I deploy a web app in tomcat, all the jars inside WEB-INF/lib will be loaded into application ClassLoader.

I have few other locations with some set/s of jars,like WEB-INF/ChildApp1/*.jar, WEB-INF/ChildApp2/*.jar.....
Based on user request I want to load some set of jars into current class loader.

Note : I don't want to create any child class loader.

My real requirement is, programmatically how to add jars into current class loader.

Comment: My requirement is to load jars from different locations into current class loader.Don't want to create child classLoader.

Comment: What you want to achieve is not standard such that you won't be able to do it without a custom classloader

Comment: the list of non standard locations will change at runtime or it is fixed?

Comment: Locations are fixed. But I can't copy those jars into WEB-INF/lib folder.

Answer (score 3):

I did it once, but this is kinda hack. Please see the code below:

```
    final URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        final Class<URLClassLoader> sysclass = URLClassLoader.class;
        // TODO some kind of a hack. Need to invent better solution.
        final Method method = sysclass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[] { URL.class });
        method.setAccessible(true);
        for (final File jar : jars) {
            method.invoke(sysloader, new URL[] { jar.toURI().toURL() });
        }
```

You need to change ClassLoader.getSystemClassloader() to class loader you want to use. You also have to check if this is an instance of URLClassloader
I think there is better solution, but this worked for me

Comment: It seems you are adding jars in System class loader.If there is any jar version collision ,then my application may not work as expected.Eg., jsonv1.jar is already loaded in webapp CL(Application class loader) then if I load jsonv2.jar in System CL as you suggested.then My application may result NoSuchMethodError or NoClassDefFoundError ?

Comment: Yes, I used system class loader (i had a very simple case and was sure that some jars will be loaded only once), but for you I suggested to use a different one. I'm not 100% sure what happens if you add another jar containing the same class. I would say it will continue using the old one. But it is only my guess, but it is easy to check

Answer (score 3):

You will need to implement your own [`WebappClassLoaderBase`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoaderBase.html) to be defined in the configuration of the [`loader`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/loader.html) in the `context.xml`.

## Implement your `WebappClassLoaderBase`

The simplest way is to extend [`WebappClassLoader`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader.html) as next

```
package my.package;

public class MyWebappClassLoader extends WebappClassLoader {

    public MyWebappClassLoader() {
    }

    public MyWebappClassLoader(final ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws LifecycleException {
        String[] paths = {"/WEB-INF/ChildApp1/lib", "/WEB-INF/ChildApp2/lib"};
        // Iterate over all the non standard locations
        for (String path : paths) {
            // Get all the resources in the current location
            WebResource[] jars = resources.listResources(path);
            for (WebResource jar : jars) {
                // Check if the resource is a jar file
                if (jar.getName().endsWith(".jar") && jar.isFile() && jar.canRead()) {
                    // Add the jar file to the list of URL defined in the parent class
                    addURL(jar.getURL());
                }
            }
        }
        // Call start on the parent class
        super.start();
    }
}
```

## Deploy your `WebappClassLoaderBase`

- Build your own `WebappClassLoaderBase` using the tomcat jar corresponding to your tomcat version that is available from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina).
- Create a jar from it
- And put the jar in **tomcat/lib** in order to make it available from the [`Common ClassLoader`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html)

## Configure your `WebappClassLoaderBase`

Define your `WebappClassLoaderBase` in the `context.xml`

```
<Context>
    ...
    <Loader loaderClass="my.package.MyWebappClassLoader" />
</Context>
```

---

It is done, now your webapps will be able to load jar files from `/WEB-INF/ChildApp1/lib` and `/WEB-INF/ChildApp2/lib`.

---

## Response Update

As you would like to do the same thing but with only a `war`, you will need to use a hack to add dynamically your `jar` files.

**Here is how you can proceed:**

## Implement a `ServletContextListener` to add your jar files

In order to add your `jar` files dynamically when the context is initialized, you need to create a `ServletContextListener` that will call [`URLClassLoader#addURL(URL)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#addURL-java.net.URL-) by refection which is an ugly hack but it works. Note that it works because the `ClassLoader` of a webapp in Tomcat is a `WebappClassLoader` which is actually a subclass of `URLClassLoader`.

```
package my.package;

public class MyServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
        try {
            // Get the method URLClassLoader#addURL(URL)
            Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", URL.class);
            // Make it accessible as the method is protected
            method.setAccessible(true);
            String[] paths = {"/WEB-INF/ChildApp1/lib", "/WEB-INF/ChildApp2/lib"};
            for (String path : paths) {
                File parent = new File(sce.getServletContext().getRealPath(path));
                File[] jars = parent.listFiles(
                    new FilenameFilter() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean accept(final File dir, final String name) {
                            return name.endsWith(".jar");
                        }
                    }
                );
                if (jars == null)
                    continue;
                for (File jar : jars) {
                    // Add the URL to the context CL which is a URLClassLoader 
                    // in case of Tomcat
                    method.invoke(
                        sce.getServletContext().getClassLoader(), 
                        jar.toURI().toURL()
                    );
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

## Declare your `ServletContextListener`

In the `web.xml` of your webapp simply add:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>my.package.MyServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thanks,I will test and let you know.First question, Why to keep WebappClassLoaderBase in tomcat shared lib(tomcat/lib),why can't tomcat create WebappClassLoaderBase CL(application class loader) from my WEB-INF/lib....Second one, WebappClassLoaderBase CL will have WEB-INF/lib +  /WEB-INF/ChildApp1/lib"  +  "/WEB-INF/ChildApp2/lib" jars ?

Comment: #1 Because a Loader is global not specific to a given webapp such that it mus be defined in the common classloader to be available at tomcat startup #2 yes

Comment: Thanks Nicolas,It worked.All external location and WEB-INF/lib jars are loaded in web-app classloader.   Concerns, This works only in tomcat.I can't deliver one jar(for shared CL) and one war(application) to clients. Can we do same programmatically ?....I mean after deploying war,  in application startup , is it possible to load all jars in single CL?

Comment: Why can't you deliver one jar and one war to your customers?

Comment: Our's is a RAD platform,Where we can develop webapps in rapid fashion.It is like, users will develop webapps and they deploy it in our cloud env or they can export apps(war's) to deploy in some other servers.If I go with one jar + one war, first it will not work in other web servers (like google app server, web logic ...) second I need to educate all users(which is not possible),  third ultimately I should deliver only wars bzc that is how people know of webapps portability.

Comment: you will need to implement your own class loader then, hopefully I already did that let me improve my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123519/discussion-between-sunil-kumar-and-nicolas-filotto).

Comment: which version of tomcat do you use?

Comment: Tomcat version 7.x and 8.x.

Comment: What I had in mind doesn't seem to work, so this is the best I can propose sorry

Comment: Checked with Updated once,Ya it is working.But If a jar of V1.0 exist in Webapp CL and  in servlet listener if we add jar of V2.0 in URL CL then by that time classes in V1.0 is already loaded in webapp CL hence even though we try to add  V2.0 in parent CL(URL CL) it will not update.

Comment: What is URL CL for you? here I only add new jar to the Webapp CL that is actually a sub class of URL CL so it is the same CL. Knowing that your usecase doesn't make much sense to me unless you try to solve a problem that cannot be solved. I'm afraid that you will need to use a bounty to get a better answer, Good Luck.